# Connectionstring issue

Tags: .net, sql-server, connection-string

The connection string generated by entity framework looks like this.

```
<add name="ETestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TestModel.csdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=bogus\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ETest;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I ftp deployed the application, created the database(i named it ETest) and created an user.
The instruction i got is:

```
In order to connect to SQL Server 2008 from Management Studio, Enterprise Manager, Query Analyzer or other client software you can use the following SQL Server address:
1.2.3.4

You may also use SQL Server address above in your application connection strings, for example:
Classic ASP (ADO Library)   Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data source=1.2.3.4;Initial catalog=databaseName;User Id=userName;Password=password;
ASP.NET (ADO.NET Library)   Server=1.2.3.4;Database=databaseName;Uid=userName;Password=password;
```

I tried the following from [www.connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com)

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword; 

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;
```

How do i have to modify the connection string to  make it work?

It seems to work like this:

```
Connection string: Data Source=dataSource;Network Library=dbmssocn;Connection Timeout=15;Packet Size=4096;Integrated Security=no;User ID=user;Password=pass;Encrypt=no;
Connection timeout: 15
Database: ETest
Datasource: dataSource
Network packet size: 4096
Server version: 10.00.4311
Work station id: WIN-HS1ITVC2D4K
```

Comment: Did you get any errors when trying to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Entity Framework there is an extra abstraction<sup>1</sup> going on. The connection string generated for you, with a couple of added line breaks:

> ```
> metadata=res://*/Models.TestModel.csdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.msl;
> provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
> provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=bogus\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ETest;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;
> ```

can be seen to contain a `provider connection string` property, the value of this property is the "normal" connection string (undoing the XML escapes):

> ```
> "Data Source=bogus\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ETest;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
> ```

You need to replace the value of the `Data Source` and `Initial Catalog` properties of this inner connection string.

---

<sup>1</sup> Essentially the EF connection string is telling the EF runtime where to get the model (from resources in an assembly) to create the in-memory model, what EF provider to use, and what connection string to pass to that provider – and it is this last piece that you need to adjust when the server, instance or database changes.

Answer (score 2):

While not a direct answer to your question, this site is useful for almost any connection string question: http://www.connectionstrings.com/.

At the risk of sounding like a commercial: It's your one-stop-shop for connection strings!

Comment: I visited that one and i tested the first 2 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;SERVER=myServerAddress;DataTypeCompatibility=80;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword
```

Hope this helps.